# Deconstructed state is not updated even in the setState callback

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

Having an issue whereby deconstructing a component's state is preventing it from being updating within setState:

```
state = {
   value: 'test',
   values: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
};
```

...

```
const { value, values } = this.state;

this.setState(
  {
    values: [...values, value],
  },
  () => {
    console.log(values);
    // this logs ["a", "b", "c"] rather than ["a", "b", "c", "test"]
  }
);
```

The expected output of values should be with the new value included but it only logs the old values. Using "this.state" works so just wondering why deconstructing the state object doesn't seem to update properly?

You can go to this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-tdd-m9d2m) and give it a try yourself if you click on the button and check the console logs.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: It is updating but you're printing the old value not the new value. So, if you click the button twice you'll see the update.

Comment: You have to console log `this.state.values`. values is still referring to the local variable which is referring to old `this.state.values`

Comment: Commented on the answer provided but yeah thanks for explaining guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following:

```
state = {value: 0}
foo = () =>{
    const { value } = this.state
    this.setState({value : value + 1}, () => console.log(value)) //0
}
```

This is happening cause `value` holds the state value from when the method `foo()` was called, even after the state's update the value of this `const` won't change cause it's equivalent to: `const value = this.state.value`. It's a reference of what this value used to be. Use the global instance of `state` in this case to get access to the updated value

```
this.setState({value : value + 1}, () => console.log(this.state.value))//1
```

Comment: Ah okay. I guess it's not an issue when doing it within the render() function as the const of this.state is being reassigned every draw so works there but not outside of render. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Exactly. It's okay to do it in render cause it's called everytime the state changes, so it always holds the current state

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like that:

```
state = {
   value: 'test',
   values: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
};

this.setState(oldState => 
  const { value, values } = oldState;
  return {
    values: [...values, value],
  },
  () => {
    console.log(values);
    // this logs ["a", "b", "c"] rather than ["a", "b", "c", "test"]
  }
);
```

In your example, you are trying to print the old values of the state, the ones that just happened before setState. So, you're basically setting values to what they used to be. setState actually also takes a callback function from which you can extract the old state. There you can destructure values etc. give it a try and good luck!